# Nginx SSL cert is override by other cert

Tags: ssl, nginx

```
server {
    server_name
        thepage.com.ar
        www.thepage.com.ar;
    location / {
        return  404;
    }
}
server {
        listen 443 ssl;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/tracker.thepage.com.ar.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/tracker.thepage.com.ar.key;

    server_name 
        tracker.thepage.com.ar;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://tracker.intranet.thepage.com.ar;
    }
}
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name
        tracker.thepage.com.ar;
    return  301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
server {
        listen  80;
        server_name
                repos.thepage.com.ar;
        return  301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/repos.thepage.com.ar.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/repos.thepage.com.ar.key;

        server_name
                repos.thepage.com.ar;
        location / {
        client_max_body_size 50m;
                proxy_pass http://repos.tracker.intranet.thepage.com.ar;
        }
}
```

When I comment the tracker.thepage.com.ar servers (ssl and normal), the fingerprint of repos.thepage.com.ar's cert is the correct.

When the tracker.thepage.com.ar is uncommented, the fingerprint of repos.thepage.com.ar is the same as tracker.thepage.com.ar,

How could I identify the problem?

Comment: It seems to be a problem with SNI, check if your server supports it http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#sni

Comment: How do you test it, in browser?

Comment: All modern browsers support SNI. How did you check fingerprint?

Comment: @zakjan Yes I tested it in browser and with `openssl s_client -connect repos.thesite.com.ar:443 < /dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -fingerprint -noout -in /dev/stdin`

Comment: @AlexeyTen I tested in command line and in browser. My NGINX supports SNI. It is strange that it is not working

Comment: You need to use -servername argument in openssl to connect with SNI